# apply border image around a large image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how can I apply a `border-image` around a large image?

HTML

```
 <div class="banner-wrapper ">
    <div class="demo">
        <img src="http://www.stickylife.com/images/u/667a4600f02d485187d4c6d757d28bdb-800.png" alt="" >
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.demo img{      border-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/SpwDTIy.png") 6 6 6 6;
border-image-width: 5px;
border-style: solid;
}
```

I am trying this but not working.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amtk9khh/1/).

EDIT:

If you check this [image: Screenshot], the lower part of my `border-image` is not showing up. With `padding:15px` It isn't working either.

Comment: Put links to images that can be accesed on your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I've added some of the images from google and it worked for me.

```
.demo img{      
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRoorWzCXfyuLKQ8cUOMPZE9Jh9sxqxv9U1bt8y0AlaQet-7dei") 6 6 6 6;
}
```

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amtk9khh/3/).

Answer (score 0):

```
.demo img{     
border: 10px solid transparent;
padding: 15px;
-webkit-border-image: url("http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/LTK/pdM/LTKpdMnAc.png") 30 round; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
-o-border-image: url("http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/LTK/pdM/LTKpdMnAc.png") 30 round; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
border-image: url("http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/LTK/pdM/LTKpdMnAc.png") 30 round;
```

}

[JSfiddle updated for you](http://jsfiddle.net/amtk9khh/4/)

Also bear in mind IE10 downawards has no support to this rule whatsoever. [CanIuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-image)

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is as belows

```
#borderimg { 
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-border-image: url(border.png) 30 round; /* Safari */
    -o-border-image: url(border.png) 30 round; /* Chrome */
    border-image: url(border.png) 30 round;
}
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_border_images.asp

Answer (score 0):

With your border image:

```
body {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #4776E6 10%, #8E54E9 90%);
}
.demo img {    
    border-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/SpwDTIy.png') 6 6 6 6;
    margin: 100px;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/amtk9khh/5/)